# Cutting a cuboid by a diagonal plane.

Tags: geometry

> Suppose we have a cuboid with dimensions $A\times B\times C$ composed of $1\times 1\times 1$ cubes with $\gcd(A,B)=gcd(A,C)=gcd(B,C)=1$.
>
> Considering any vertex of the cuboid as origin, say $O$, we select $3$ vertices $P$,$Q$ and $R$ such that $OP$, $OQ$ and $OR$ are mutually perpendicular. If we cut the cuboid along the plane $PQR$ in two parts, how many $1\times 1\times 1$ cubes will be cut?

I have till now solved the problem in $2D$ system with a line slicing an $A\times B$ rectangle through the diagonal. In that case the answer turns out to be $A+B-1$. With similar logic I established that any needle through the diagonal of cuboid will pierce through $A+B+C-2$ cubes (correct me if I'm incorrect). But I could not wrap my head around the cuboid and plane problem.

Comment: Why the down-votes? :(

Comment: I don't know, @Prateek, but [here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Thanks @Shaun got it now :)

Comment: Do you mean how many $1 \times 1$ squares on the surface, or how many $1 \times 1 \times 1$ cubes?

Comment: Cubes. @augurar Thanks for pointing. For the surface the solution will be trivial ie. $ 2*(A+B+C)-3 $

Comment: Also, are you sure you don't need $\gcd(A,B)=\gcd(A,C)=\gcd(B,C)=1$?

Comment: @augurar Thanks again. Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with the 2D case.  Consider an $A \times B$ rectangle with a line through $(0, A)$ and $(B, 0)$.  The line contains all points $(x,y)$ satisfying $Ax+By = AB$.  We will say that points $(x,y)$ such that $Ax + By < AB$ are *below* the line.  Notice that there is a one-to-one correspondence between squares intersected by the line, and lattice points on the boundary of the rectangle below the line!

[image: 2D example]

This approach generalizes to $n$ dimensions.  For the $A \times B \times C$ cuboid, the answer is:

> $(AB+BC+AC-1)/2$